# How to make a rotate + flip compound transform?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to figure out how to make a `UIProgressView` fill from right to left with increasingly higher `progress` values. I thought if I just rotated the component it would be fine, however the shading now appears upside down. How do I add a 'flip vertically' transform to complete the task?

Note, the shading issue affects < iOS 7.

Here's what I have so far, the 2nd line of code does not work correctly, it makes the control disappear.

```
CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); // rotate 180 degrees (but now it's upside down)
CGAffineTransform flipTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // flip 90 degrees to bring it the right way up
myProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotateTransform, flipTransform);
```

NOTE:
I'm not trying to animate anything

UPDATE:
Instead of trying to figure out two transforms to achieve this (i.e., one 180 rotation + 180 vertical invert), just one horizontal 180 invert should achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little roundabout but this does the trick…

`CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0));`

[image]

Logging out the transform

`NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:self.progress.transform]);`

gives

> CGAffineTransform: {{-0.99999982, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}}

and shows a missing `a` value of `-1.0` in your attempt to create the transform.

Comment: That's the one! I just hardcoded it like this:    `myProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`